# Как можно заменить моржа в коде питон?

Tags: python

Вот задача, по которой я писал код:
Представление в виде суммы
Дано натуральное число n. Найдите все тройки натуральных чисел x⩽y⩽z таких, что n={x}^{2} + {y}^{2} + {z}^{2}
Формат входных данных
В первой строке содержится целое число n (1⩽n⩽106).

Формат результата
Выведите все тройки x,y,z в лексикографическом порядке.
Вот сам код:

```
n = int(input())
square_roots = {}
i = 1
while i * i <= n:
    square_roots[i * i] = i
    i += 1
x = 1
while x * x <= n // 3:
    y = x
    while y * y <= (n - x * x) // 2:
        if z := square_roots.get(n - x * x - y * y):
            print(x, y, z)
        y += 1
    x += 1
```

в строчке  if z := square_roots.get(n - x * x - y * y):

использован морж, как его можно заменить? Проблема в том, что это задача из дз, а система сдачи пот питон 3.6.6, а морж под 3.8

Comment: Прочитать определение моржа и заменить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например так:

```
    z = square_roots.get(n - x * x - y * y)
    if z:
        print(x, y, z)
```

а как вы сами писали код если не можете его переписать?

Comment: спасибо! я просто новичок

Comment: Только из этого ответа я догадался, что такое "морж" из вопроса

Comment: моржовый оператор (walrus)

Comment: @Zhihar, Спасибщ, прочел в инете (вообще-то я не питонист, время от времени правлю какие-то скрипты, в основном на Python2). Не понимаю, почему они (авторы питона) вообще ввели его, а не расширили семантику обычного оператора присваивания (=) при его использовании внутри выражения. Тем более, что это всегда было в Си

Comment: А, догадался. У них же вместо `==` (сравнение на равенство) тот же `=`